# Get Clicked ListView item attributes

Tags: c#, listview, windows-8, microsoft-metro, onitemclick

I have a Windows 8 application with a ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="EventListView" ItemClick="EventListView_ItemClick_1" IsItemClickEnabled="True"/>
```

There is some Event objects (a separate class with string attributes like EventType, Description, Time, etc..) that is the source of the ListView:

```
List<Event> eventlist = new List<Event>{
    new Event(CONNECTION,   "Disconnected",         DateTime.Now.ToString(),  MONITOR,         "SAMSUNG M5",        CONNECTION_IMG,   RED),
    new Event(SYNC,         "Synchronised",         DateTime.Now.ToString(),  LAPTOP,          "ASUS X402",         SYNC_IMG,         BLUE),
    new Event(WARNING,      "Overheated!",          DateTime.Now.ToString(),  PRINTER,         "CANON MP280",       WARING_IMG,       YELLOW),
};

EventListView.ItemsSource = eventlist;
```

I tried to access the info of the clicked item, but its seems to be not set:

```
private void EventListView_ItemClick_1(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Event item = sender as Event;
    GetInfoText.Text = item.Description.ToString();
}
```

How could I get the event attributes of the clicked item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Event` object is stored in the `e` parameter:

```
private void EventListView_ItemClick_1(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Event item = e.ClickedItem as Event;
    GetInfoText.Text = item.Description.ToString();
}
```

I believe the `sender` parameter is the listview.

Answer (score 2):

Since you named your ListView **EventListView** you can do the following:

```
private void EventListView_ItemClick_1(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Event item = EventListView.SelectedItem as Event;
    GetInfoText.Text = item.Description.ToString();
}
```

At least, it is the way I do.