# How to handler click item from string inside of listview Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I've been reading [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb386b/implementing-navigation-drawer-for-windows-phone-8-1/) article about Navigation Drawer and i Succeed, but how can i create a Click Event to each item i have inside of mu ListView?
i have that Array and bind all this to listview!

```
string[] menuItems = new string[5] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5" };
ListMenuItems.ItemsSource = menuItems.ToList();
```

XAML.....

```
<Grid x:Name="ListFragment" Background="#F4F4F4">
            <ListView x:Name="ListMenuItems" SelectedItem="true" SelectionChanged="ListMenuItems_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </Grid>
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Clicked ListView item attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274071/get-clicked-listview-item-attributes)

Comment: Its little bit different about what i'm trying to do @igrali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an event handler for [ItemClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242904) event of ListView. You also need to set [IsItemClickEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.isitemclickenabled) property to true.

```
<ListView x:Name="listview"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="listView_ItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
..
..
private void listView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) {
      // Code here
}
```